# Trying to access member function of nested class through pointer

Tags: c++, class, pointers, tree, member

I'm very new to C++, and think this question fundamentally relates to pointers; researched around but couldn't find anything obvious that related to the context below.

I've outlined my code structure, to highlight the problem I have, which is trying to access the nested `Node` class member function `isLeftChild` through the pointer `root` to constant `Node`; I could make the `isLeftChild` a member function of the `Tree` class, but feel it more logical for the `isLeftChild` to be a member function of the nested `Node` class.

```
class Tree {

    class Node {
        public:
            bool isLeftChild(void);
    };

    Node const* root;
    public:
        void traverse(Node const* root);
};

void Tree::traverse(Node const* root) {
    // *** Line below gives compile error: request for member 'isLeftChild' in 
    //     'root', which is of non-class type 'const Tree::Node*'
    if ( root.isLeftChild() ) {
        cout << "[is left child]";
    }
}

bool Tree::Node::isLeftChild(void){
    bool hasParent = this->parent != NULL;

    if ( hasParent ) {
        return this == this->parent->left;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

How would I access this member function, from within the `traverse` member function? Does the issue centre around the fact that `root` is a pointer?

Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a pointer to const parameter, you can only call const methods on it.

Try

```
 bool isLeftChild() const;
```

And add the "const" to the implementation as well.

Comment: Thanks @molbdnilo was just trying to add in the `const` before I saw your answer; was trying `bool const isLeftChild()` but I presume setting `const` after `isLeftChild()` sets the method as a `const` method, as opposed to the return type `bool` being set to a `const`.

Answer (score 1):

Chenge this:

```
root.isLeftChild()
```

to this:

```
root->isLeftChild()
```

The operator `.` will act on an *object*.

The operator `->` will act on a *pointer to an object*.  Like `root`.

That's why the error was telling you that `root` was a non-class type.  It's a pointer type.

Comment: Hi @DrewDormann amended to `root->isLeftChild()` but got compilation error: _passing 'const Tree::Node' as 'this' argument of 'bool Tree::Node::isLeftChild()' discards qualifiers_ I've added the content of the `isLeftChild` definition to my code above, in case there may be an additional issue here.